# SQL Server SELECT Query to show sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

It ll be great if you guys help me with this

```
product_no        prod_name      qty                    DOA 
---------------------------------------------------------------
 1                   2BL         4                    12/12/14
 2                   CCN         6                    14/12/14
 3                   MNN         7                    16/12/14 
 3                   MNN         5                   17/12/14  
 2                   CCN         6                    02/01/15
 3                   MNN         7                    06/01/15
```

I need output in single select query if i select DOA between `1/12/14` to `30/12/14`

It should show `sum (qty)` as opening, `prod_name` and rest of qty and product i.e(`02/01/15` to `06/01/15`) in another column as purchase (DOA not in `1/12/14` to `30/12/14`). Thanks in advance

Comment: You question is so unclear, it made me dance for a while

Comment: Are your dates really stored like that (as string), or are they stored like they should be, using date types for the column?

Comment: Also, why store the product name in that table, when the product key is clearly a key into a different table that should hold the authoritative name for the product?

Comment: And is it possible to have more than one record for a product on a particular day?

Comment: yes possible to have

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, of course, the point rightly raised by Joel in his comment about date formats is taken care of, by you:

```
Select product_no, prod_name, 
Sum(Case When DOA >= '01/12/2014' And DOA <= '30/12/2014' Then Qty Else 0 End) as openingQty, 

Sum(Case When DOA < '01/12/2014' Or DOA > '30/12/2014' Then Qty Else 0 End) as purchaseQty 

From Table_Name_Here Group By 
 product_no, prod_name
```